# What does gita anvay yog samanvay mean?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, shloka

I came across this verse via a speech I heard at a temple. And I would like to know more about this sentence or verse or something describe about
What I have understood till now is that

Geeta anvay yog samanvay

Geeta meaning the bhagwad geeta
Anvay meaning relieving from sins
Yog meaning our actions 
Samanvay meaning the correlation between any two object
Can anyone help me out with the whole meaning of this phrase or verse

Comment: It means "understanding and interpretation of Gita results in the culmination of knowledge of yoga".  Yoga is the Supreme path to liberation and living life according to the Gita helps us attain it.

Comment: YOG means to join or to make linkup between two things, SAMANVAY means to make blended two thing, i.e. soul & God..!!

Answer (score 2):

Samanvay can be broken into two words: sam+anvay. Sam means to join together and anvaya means to put things in order. It means to join together in order to methodically engage in common pursuit.

Yoga- according to my understanding it means to do, to join, to go forward and get yourself engaged to GOD. Like attain self knowledge through our 
Mother Geeta various yogas- gyan, karma and bhakti yoga. synthesis of this can lead you to serenity.

Samanvay also  means synthesis, coordination, balance and a logical connection with God. If you logically explain the true meaning of Geeta you will attain self knowledge and self attainment but blindly following Geeta without any logical explanation is same like following our old rituals and customs.

This is just as per my understanding.. hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

co-relation between the action (what u r doing) and thought (thinking at the time of action).

So thinking should be pure/non-attachment/truthful/to save other or all.

If thinking would be wrong then action would come out like that. So all these yog are to make thinking pure/truthfull.

Comment: Do use references to support your point.

Answer (score 0):

The words Yoga, Anvaya and Samnvaya have a lot of meanings. Although, I will mention the most relevant ones in this context.

> *Yoga* means - union
>
> *Anvaya* means - to follow, be connected with, conform to
>
> The verb *Samanvitah* means - to be endowed with

Hence, ***Geeta anvayah yoga samanvayah* means *by following, being connected with and conforming to the Gita; one is endowed with the union (with Divinity)***

Reference used: [The Practical Sanskrit-English Dictionary](https://archive.org/details/ldpd_7285627_000) by *Vaman Shivaram Apte.*